# Using R to sample 3 proportion variables so that the three samples add to 1

Tags: r, random, model, sample

I have a data set that is split into 3 profiles

- Profile 1 = 0.478 (95% confidence interval: 0.4,  0.56)
- Profile 2 = 0.415 (95% confidence interval: 0.34, 0.49)
- Profile 3 = 0.107 (95% confidence interval: 0.06, 0.15)

Profile 1 + Profile 2 + Profile 3 = 1

I want to create a stochastic model that selects a value for each profile from each proportion's confidence interval. I want to keep that these add up to one. I have been using

```
pro1_prop<- rpert (1, 0.4, 0.478, 0.56)              
pro2_prop<- rpert (1, 0.34, 0.415, 0.49)   
pro3_prop<- 1- (pro1_prop + pro2_prop)
```

But this does not seem robust enough. Also on some iterations, (pro1_prop + pro2_prop) >1 which results in a negative value for pro3_prop. Is there a better way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to sample from the posterior distributions of the proportions using Bayesian methods. I'll assume a multinomial model, where each observation is one of the three profiles.

Say the counts data for the three profiles are 76, 66, and 17.

Using a Dirichlet prior distribution, Dir(1/2, 1/2, 1/2), the posterior is also Dirichlet-distributed: Dir(76.5, 66.5, 17.5), which can be sampled using normalized random gamma variates.

```
x <- c(76, 66, 17) # observations

# take 1M samples of the proportions from the posterior distribution
theta <- matrix(rgamma(3e6, rep(x + 1/2, each = 1e6)), ncol = 3)
theta <- theta/rowSums(theta)
head(theta)
#>           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,] 0.5372362 0.3666786 0.09608526
#> [2,] 0.4008362 0.4365053 0.16265852
#> [3,] 0.5073144 0.3686412 0.12404435
#> [4,] 0.4752601 0.4367119 0.08802793
#> [5,] 0.4428575 0.4520680 0.10507456
#> [6,] 0.4494075 0.4178494 0.13274311

# compare the Bayesian credible intervals with the frequentist confidence intervals
cbind(
  t(mapply(function(i) quantile(theta[,i], c(0.025, 0.975)), seq_along(x))),
  t(mapply(function(y) setNames(prop.test(y, sum(x))$conf.int, c("2.5%", "97.5%")), x))
)
#>            2.5%     97.5%       2.5%     97.5%
#> [1,] 0.39994839 0.5537903 0.39873573 0.5583192
#> [2,] 0.33939396 0.4910900 0.33840295 0.4959541
#> [3,] 0.06581214 0.1614677 0.06535702 0.1682029
```

If samples within the individual 95% CIs are needed, simply reject samples that fall outside the desired interval.

Comment: While your approach has some merits, 95% CI advice is complete nonsense

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, can you elaborate some on what is nonsense? Is it the OP's desire to sample within the 95% CI, or the rejection approach, or something else?

Comment: Rejection. How you suppose to reject sampled troika of values? Single value out of interval? But it is 95% CI, there SHOULD be some values outside the interval.

Comment: Let me write couple thoughts on the sampling.

Comment: Agreed that the OP very well may want the sampled values to reflect the full posterior, rather than within a set of 95% CIs. I suspect this may be somewhat of an XY problem, and a better answer would spend some time on that. The suggestion to perform rejection was based on the OP's statement "I want to create a stochastic model that selects a value for each profile from each proportion's confidence interval." So, yes, rejection would be based on a single value out of the desired interval.

Comment: Ok, wrote my thoughts as an answer

Comment: Having read your thoughts, I still don't see how the suggestion to reject samples from the posterior is complete nonsense given the OP's explicit desire to have all sampled proportions fall within respective interval. Note that the OP didn't specify any sampling method. One could come up with any number of ways to generate three values that sum to 1 with interval constraints on each value. This approach seems reasonable in that the resulting distribution being sampled is at least proportional to a relatively non-informative posterior distribution in the allowable region.

Comment: You have to control stddev/variance for all three variables. Realistically, you need 6 parameters distribution, to control means and stddev/variance. "One could come up with any number of ways to generate three values that sum to 1 with interval constraints on each value." Sure, but how many parameters you need for that way of yours? Dir(a1,a2,a3) doesn't have enough, I believe

Comment: The goal isn't to find Dirichlet parameters that give the desired CIs. There is no need to. Better to find a distribution that corresponds to the likelihood of the proportions. That distribution is the Dirichlet posterior I derived. That being said, the last table I presented does show the similarity between the credible intervals of the marginal distributions and the individual CIs.

Comment: Similarity, sure. But won't be exact match for CI no matter what you do - not enough degrees of freedom

Comment: Again, there is no need to match for CI. Nothing in the problem statement suggests the need to equate the quantiles of the sampling distribution with the CI. Keep in mind that while confidence intervals and credible intervals have numeric and some conceptual similarities, they are fundamentally different. A 95% confidence interval does **not** mean that the parameter is expected to fall within the interval 95% of the time.

Comment: Thank you! This works well for what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Sample all three values (for example from a pert distribution, as you did) and norm those values afterwards so they add up to one.

Sampling all three values independently from each other and then dividing by their sum so that the normed values add up to one seems to be the easiest option as it is quite hard to sample from the set of legal values directly.

Legal values: [image: legal values]

The downside of my approach is that the normed values are not necessarily legal (i.e. in the range of the confidence intervals) any more. However, for these values using a pert distribution, this only happens about 0.5% of the time.

Code:

```r
library(plotly)
library(freedom)
library(data.table)

# define lower (L) and upper (U) bounds and expected values (E)
prof1L <- 0.4
prof1E <- 0.478
prof1U <- 0.56
prof2L <- 0.34
prof2E <- 0.415
prof2U <- 0.49
prof3L <- 0.06
prof3E <- 0.107
prof3U <- 0.15

dt <- as.data.table(expand.grid(
  Profile1 = seq(prof1L, prof1U, by = 0.002),
  Profile2 = seq(prof2L, prof2U, by = 0.002),
  Profile3 = seq(prof3L, prof3U, by = 0.002)
))

# color based on how far the points are away from the center
dt[, color := abs(Profile1 - prof1E) + abs(Profile2 - prof2E) + abs(Profile3 - prof3E)]
# only keep those points that (almost) add up to one
dt <- dt[abs(Profile1 + Profile2 + Profile3 - 1) < 0.01]

# plot the legal values
fig <- plot_ly(dt, x = ~Profile1, y = ~Profile2, z = ~Profile3, color = ~color, colors = c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E')) %>%
  add_markers()
fig

# try to simulate the legal values:
# first sample without considering the condition that the profiles need to add up to 1
nSample <- 100000
dtSample <- data.table(
  Profile1Sample = rpert(nSample, prof1L, prof1U, prof1E),
  Profile2Sample = rpert(nSample, prof2L, prof2U, prof2E),
  Profile3Sample = rpert(nSample, prof3L, prof3U, prof3E)
)

# we want to norm the samples by dividing by their sum
dtSample[, SampleSums := Profile1Sample + Profile2Sample + Profile3Sample]
dtSample[, Profile1SampleNormed := Profile1Sample / SampleSums]
dtSample[, Profile2SampleNormed := Profile2Sample / SampleSums]
dtSample[, Profile3SampleNormed := Profile3Sample / SampleSums]

# now get rid of the cases where the normed values are not legal any more
# (e.g. Profile 1 = 0.56, Profile 2 = 0.38, Profile 3 = 0.06 => dividing by their sum
# will make Profile 3 have an illegal value)
dtSample <- dtSample[
  prof1L <= Profile1SampleNormed & Profile1SampleNormed <= prof1U &
  prof2L <= Profile2SampleNormed & Profile2SampleNormed <= prof2U &
  prof3L <= Profile3SampleNormed & Profile3SampleNormed <= prof3U
]

# see if the sampled values follow the desired distribution
hist(dtSample$Profile1SampleNormed)
hist(dtSample$Profile2SampleNormed)
hist(dtSample$Profile3SampleNormed)
```

Histogram of normed sampled values for Profile 1: [image: Histogram of normed sampled values]

Answer (score -1):

Ok, some thoughts on the matter.

Lets think about [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), as one providing RV summed up to 1.

We're talking about Dir(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>), and have to find needed a<sub>i</sub>.

From the expression for E[X<sub>i</sub>]=a<sub>i</sub>/Sum(i, a<sub>i</sub>), it is obvious we could get three ratios solving equations

a<sub>1</sub>/Sum(i, a<sub>i</sub>) = 0.478
a<sub>2</sub>/Sum(i, a<sub>i</sub>) = 0.415
a<sub>3</sub>/Sum(i, a<sub>i</sub>) = 0.107

Note, that we have only solved for RATIOS. In other words, if in the expression for E[Xi]=a<sub>i</sub>/Sum(i, a<sub>i</sub>) we multiply a<sub>i</sub> by the same value, mean will stay the same. So we have freedom to choose multiplier m, and what will change is the variance/std.dev. Large multiplier means smaller variance, tighter sampled values around the means

So we could choose m freely to satisfy three 95% CI conditions, three equations for variance but only one df. So it is not possible in general.

One cold play with numbers and the code